# Multi dynamics d3 charts on a same page

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I try to display several d3 flare bubble charts with a php foreach. I use to make each var unique but without any result. If My array had only one field of data this is working but with more it fail...

The array with the datas

```
$d3array = array('sitewebfonctionmanquante' => $sitewebfonctionmanquante,'aimerezsiteweb' => $aimerezsiteweb);
```

The script with the information for d3 chart :

```
<script>var sitewebfonctionmanquante = '{"name": "citation", "children": [{"name": "RECHERCHE", "size": 25},{"name": "QUESTIONS", "size": 18},{"name": "CRIDON", "size": 15},{"name": "REPONSES", "size": 13},{"name": "MOTEUR", "size": 11},{"name": "POSEES", "size": 11},{"name": "ACCES", "size": 9},{"name": "N", "size": 7},{"name": "BASE", "size": 7},{"name": "ECRITES", "size": 7},{"name": "SITE", "size": 6},{"name": "THEMES", "size": 4},{"name": "REPONSE", "size": 4},{"name": "PAS", "size": 4},{"name": "Y", "size": 4},{"name": "LES", "size": 4},{"name": "CONSULTATION", "size": 3},{"name": "ON", "size": 3},{"name": "AI", "size": 3},{"name": "QUESTION", "size": 3},{"name": "DOCUMENTATION", "size": 3},{"name": "CONSULTE", "size": 3},{"name": "COMME", "size": 3},{"name": "BA", "size": 3},{"name": "PROBLEME", "size": 3},{"name": "ENSEMBLE", "size": 3},{"name": "FONCTION", "size": 3},{"name": "..", "size": 3},{"name": "CAHIERS", "size": 3},{"name": "TITRE", "size": 3},{"name": "ETU", "size": 3},{"name": "CONFRERES", "size": 3},{"name": "RETROUVER", "size": 3},{"name": "MAN", "size": 3},{"name": "PARIS", "size": 3},{"name": "JA", "size": 2},{"name": "FORMATIONS", "size": 2},{"name": "AVOIR", "size": 2},{"name": "QUESTIONS/REPONSES", "size": 2},{"name": "PERFORMANT", "size": 2},{"name": "CETTE", "size": 2},{"name": ".", "size": 2},{"name": "SEMBLE", "size": 2},{"name": "TROUVE", "size": 2},{"name": "BULLETIN", "size": 2},{"name": "TEMPS", "size": 2},{"name": "FAUDRAIT", "size": 2},{"name": "ACCESSIBLE", "size": 2},{"name": "NEANT", "size": 2},{"name": "QU", "size": 2},{"name": "MEME", "size": 2},{"name": "SON", "size": 2},{"name": "FAITES", "size": 2},{"name": "RECHERCHES", "size": 2},{"name": "AUCUNE", "size": 2},{"name": "C", "size": 2},{"name": "EST", "size": 2},{"name": "INFORMATIONS", "size": 2},{"name": "PUBLICATION", "size": 2},{"name": "ASSURANCE", "size": 2},{"name": "MATIERE", "size": 2},{"name": "T", "size": 2},{"name": "RAS", "size": 2},{"name": "LA", "size": 2},{"name": "LYON", "size": 2},{"name": "POSE", "size": 2},{"name": "VIE", "size": 2},{"name": "PUISSANT", "size": 2},{"name": "ACTUALITE", "size": 2},{"name": "CONSULTER", "size": 2},{"name": "GLOBALE", "size": 2},{"name": "EFFICACE", "size": 2},{"name": "DIFFICILE", "size": 2},{"name": "RAPPORT", "size": 2},{"name": "CLES", "size": 2},{"name": "ECRITE", "size": 2},{"name": "MOTS", "size": 2},{"name": "LE", "size": 2}

<script>var aimerezsiteweb = '{"name": "citation", "children": [{"name": "CALCUL", "size": 3},{"name": "PERMETTANT", "size": 3},{"name": "COMPRENDRE", "size": 2},{"name": "DIRECTEMENT", "size": 2},{"name": "DIVERS", "size": 2},{"name": "CALCULS", "size": 3},{"name": "FISCALITE", "size": 2},{"name": "ACTUELLE", "size": 2},{"name": "DOMMAGE", "size": 2},{"name": "AVOIR", "size": 6},{"name": "ACTUALITE", "size": 2},{"name": "JURIDIQUE", "size": 7},{"name": "TEMPS", "size": 4},{"name": "TROUVER", "size": 2},{"name": "DOCUMENTATION", "size": 7},{"name": "/", "size": 3},{"name": "MO", "size": 4},{"name": "CLAUSES", "size": 3},{"name": "EGALEMENT", "size": 3},{"name": "POUVOIR", "size": 3},{"name": "POSER", "size": 6},{"name": "QUESTIONS", "size": 20},{"name": "COMPTE", "size": 5},{"name": "ETU", "size": 3},{"name": "FAIRE", "size": 3},{"name": "PROFITER", "size": 2},{"name": "ENSEMBLE", "size": 4},{"name": "MAN", "size": 2},{"name": "QU", "size": 4},{"name": "CAHIERS", "size": 2},{"name": "CRIDON", "size": 14},{"name": "ACQUISITION", "size": 2},{"name": "USUFRUIT", "size": 2},{"name": "DROITS", "size": 5},{"name": "NOUS", "size": 2},{"name": "SOUVENT", "size": 2},{"name": "DONT", "size": 2},{"name": "SI", "size": 3},{"name": "FRAIS", "size": 2},{"name": "VENTE", "size": 2},{"name": ".", "size": 2},{"name": "POINTS", "size": 2},{"name": "TABLE", "size": 3},{"name": "TYPE", "size": 3},{"name": "PRATIQUE", "size": 3},{"name": "DOSSIERS", "size": 2},{"name": "ACCES", "size": 12},{"name": "BASE", "size": 8},{"name": "DONNEES", "size": 4},{"name": "POSEES", "size": 7},{"name": "CONSULTER", "size": 4},{"name": "REPONSES", "size": 17},{"name": "QUESTIONS,", "size": 3},{"name": "AUTRES", "size": 2},{"name": "COMME", "size": 4},{"name": "BA", "size": 3},{"name": "N", "size": 4},{"name": "NOTAMMENT", "size": 2},{"name": "JA", "size": 4},{"name": "THEMES", "size": 4},{"name": "EXEMPLE", "size": 3},{"name": "SUJETS", "size": 2},{"name": "CHAT", "size": 2},{"name": "QUESTION", "size": 5},{"name": "MOTEUR", "size": 6},{"name": "RECHERCHE", "size": 11},{"name": "APPORTEES", "size": 2},{"name": "MES", "size": 4},{"name": "AUSSI", "size": 2},{"name": "S", "size": 3},{"name": "DIRECT", "size": 2},{"name": "CI", "size": 3},{"name": "SSUS", "size": 3},{"name": "VEILLE", "size": 6},{"name": "MA", "size": 2},{"name": "AINSI", "size": 2},{"name": "ACCESSIBLE", "size": 2},{"name": "ECRITES", "size": 5},{"name": "RAS", "size": 2},{"name": "I", "size": 5},{"name": "M", "size": 6},{"name": "POURQUOI", "size": 2},{"name": "REVUES", "size": 2},{"name": "BOR", "size": 2},{"name": "MEILLEUR", "size": 2},{"name": "BASES", "size": 3},{"name": "PRATIQUES", "size": 3},{"name": "PIECES", "size": 2},{"name": "AVONS", "size": 2},{"name": "CERTAINES", "size": 2},{"name": "CONSEILS", "size": 2},{"name": "LOIS", "size": 2},{"name": "DONNEE", "size": 2},{"name": "..", "size": 2},{"name": "FICHES", "size": 2},{"name": "AFIN", "size": 2},{"name": "LYON", "size": 3},{"name": "ARTICLES", "size": 2},{"name": "C", "size": 2},{"name": "EST", "size": 3},{"name": "CES", "size": 2},{"name": "COUVRIR", "size": 2},{"name": "AI", "size": 2},{"name": ",", "size": 3},{"name": "MEME", "size": 2},{"name": "CEUX", "size": 2},{"name": "VOUS", "size": 2},{"name": "POURRIEZ", "size": 2},{"name": "CHAQUE", "size": 2},{"name": "SITE", "size": 3},{"name": "HABITU", "size": 2},{"name": "SERAIT", "size": 2},{"name": "CONSULTATIONS", "size": 4},{"name": "CREATION", "size": 2},{"name": "LA", "size": 2},{"name": "NOTAIRE", "size": 3},{"name": "CONFRERES", "size": 3},{"name": "JOUR", "size": 3},{"name": "PLUS", "size": 3},{"name": "RNIERES", "size": 2},{"name": "PUBLICS", "size": 2},{"name": ">", "size": 4},{"name": "CONTRAT", "size": 2},{"name": "POSSIBILITE", "size": 2},{"name": "CRIDON,", "size": 2},{"name": "RECUE", "size": 2},{"name": "VALUES", "size": 2}]}'</script>
```

And the php code :

```
<?php
        foreach($d3array as $d3key => $d3){
?>
<script>
var diameter = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(1.5);

var <?php echo $d3key; ?>_svg = d3.select("#<?php echo $d3key; ?>_d3").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr("class", "bubble");

<?php echo $d3key; ?>_root = JSON.parse(<?php echo $d3key; ?>);     
  var <?php echo $d3key; ?>_node = <?php echo $d3key; ?>_svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(<?php echo $d3key; ?>_root))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  <?php echo $d3key; ?>_node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.packageName + " => " + d.className + ": " + format(d.value) + " citations"; });

  <?php echo $d3key; ?>_node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  <?php echo $d3key; ?>_node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
function classes(root) {
  var classes = [];

  function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
  }

  recurse(null, root);
  return {children: classes};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
</script>         
<?php
        }
?>
```

Comment: Well you realise the code you've pasted is missing a closing '</script>' tag? In fact that object isn't even closed with a single quote/semicolon etc in the middle of the data for the d3 chart

Comment: Shame on me I use a code to generate the source and I outside the ended script tag. Thanks for your observation I pass 2 hours to find an error on the d3.js code....

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't on the d3 code but on this code to generate the data source :

```
foreach($d3array as $d3key => $d3){
    //print_r($d3);
    $k = 0;
    echo '<script>var '.$d3key.' = \'{"name": "citation", "children": [';
    foreach($d3 as $key => $value){

    if($value > 1){    
        if($k == 0){
                    echo '{"name": "'.$key.'", "size": '.$value.'}';
                } else {
                    echo ',{"name": "'.$key.'", "size": '.$value.'}';
                }
        $k++;
    }    
}    
//print_r($key2);

}
echo ']}\'</script>';
```

Indeed the script ending tag was outside the foreach ... The good code is here :

```
foreach($d3array as $d3key => $d3){
    //print_r($d3);
    $k = 0;
    echo '<script>var '.$d3key.' = \'{"name": "citation", "children": [';
    foreach($d3 as $key => $value){

    if($value > 1){    
        if($k == 0){
                    echo '{"name": "'.$key.'", "size": '.$value.'}';
                } else {
                    echo ',{"name": "'.$key.'", "size": '.$value.'}';
                }
        $k++;
    }    
}    
//print_r($key2);
echo ']}\'</script>';

}
```

Thanks user2356315 to see this error